# Web Socket server stops working on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, websocket

I have server on my IIS that contains WCF Service "MyService.svc" which works with net.tcp protocol and generic handler (Device.ashx file, which works with web socket connection). My desktop app is a client that connects to "MyService.svc" by net.tcp protocol. Also i have mobile apps which connects to Device.ashx by websocket protocol. Everything seems good but i have one problem. After some time mobile apps can't connect to the server, but desktop app working good. Should I look for problem in IIS settings or in my code?

Comment: They cannot reconnect? I mean, can they drop the current connection and try to connect again?

Comment: They can not reconnect until i reboot the pool